# knockout validation inner observable validation is not triggred

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following `JS` object:

```
var form= function () {

    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Name is required.'
        }
    });
    self.Manager = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Manager is required.'
        }
    });
    self.Email = ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Email is required.'
        },
        email: {
            message: 'Entered Email is not valid.'
        }
    });

    self.Players = ko.observableArray([]);

}
```

`Players` array in the above `JS` object is populated using the following `JS` object using the `new Player()` syntax:

```
 var Player = function () {

        var self = this;

        self.FirstName= ko.observable().extend({
            required: {
                message: 'Player First Nameis required.'
            }
        });

        self.LastName= ko.observable().extend({
            required: {
                message: 'Player Last Name is required.'
            }
        });
    }
```

And I have used the following settings for `knockout-validation` library:

```
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    decorateInputElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'error',
    grouping: {
        deep: true,
        observable: true
    }
}, true);
```

I am using the `viewModel.errors.showAllMessages()` to display all the error messages in the view model. The problem I am facing is that the validations for the `player` object are not getting triggered as it is present inside the `Form` object. I have even set the `deep` property to `true` but even that is not working, what could be the issue?

Comment: can you setup a fiddle that would be helpful . even you use `validatedObservable` .

Comment: Please try to extend your code into a [mcve]. If I do so myself, and add the bits missing to get it up and running (but stick to the code you provided verbatim), [it works as expected and player last names get validated just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/2a7t72be/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you will need to use { live: true } to track errors from objects that are added to observable arrays.

Longer answer:

I've used Jeroen's fiddle as a starting point and assumed that what you want is to show error messages for all validatable observables of all the players.

Use ko.validation.group(vm, options) to get the list of errors. It is the returned object (a computed observable returning an array of errors) that exposes showAllMessages function.

By default it will not perform a deep traversal of the supplied view model, so you will only get errors for Name, Manager, and Email properties (as I assume you are getting currently).

To make it use deep traversal you can supply { deep: true } option. That should give you errors for all players that were in the array at the time *group* function is called.

If you want it to also track objects added to observable arrays (players in your case) after *group* function is called, you can use { live: true } option. It will create a subscription on the array and update the list of errors each time the array is modified. Here is the issue that added it: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/pull/223

Below is the relevant snipped and here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2a7t72be/1/

```
var form = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.showErrors = function(){
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
    };

    // ...

    self.Players = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.errors =   ko.validation.group(self, { deep: true, live: true });
}
```

PS. You can of course configure grouping options when calling validation.init (just do it before your call to *group*).